# How to kill processes running on a port only if the port is open?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Currently, I am able to kill a process running on a port with:

```
//other scripts that should be executed
...........................
sudo kill $( sudo lsof -i:9005 -t )
...........................
//other scripts that should be executed
```

Now, I want to first test if the port 9005 is actually open and then only try to kill it.If the port is not open, I don't want to execute the kill script. I want to ensure that subsequent scripts are executed irrespective of whether the port is open or close. So, I am looking for something like:

```
//other scripts that should be executed
.............
<test-if-port-9005-is-open>  && sudo kill $( sudo lsof -i:9005 -t )
.............
// other scripts that should be executed
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the output of `lsof -i:9005 -t` will by definition be empty when the port is not open.  `xargs` on Linux has an option for handling this:

```
sudo lsof -i:9005 -t | xargs -r sudo kill
```

or you can simply check the exit code of `lsof`; it will be non-zero to signal an error if it didn't find anything to report:

```
if pids=$(sudo lsof -i:9005 -t); then
    sudo kill $pids
fi
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. Just one question, `pids` will now hold the list of all the processes listening on port 9005 ? (*in case there are multiple processes listening on a port* )

Comment: Yeah, the output from `lsof` in this mode is a list of PIDs, separated by newlines.  But it's not just the listening process; any process handling a client (and so no longer listening; and, you can't really have more than one process actually listening) will also be printed.  Not quoting `$pids` causes the shell to render them as a list of space-separated arguments on a single line.

Comment: Actually, that means that the output of `sudo lsof -i:9005 -t` could be non-empty if you have killed the main listening process, but still have clients being handled by child processes of it.  Whether this is a bug or a feature depends on what you are actually hoping to accomplish.

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this:

```
nc -zv 127.0.0.1 9005 && sudo kill $( sudo lsof -i:9005 -t )
```

It kills the process if a tcp-connection was successful on the provided port. Then it moves on. As tested on macOS High Sierra.

Comment: The solution works well when the port is open. But, when the port is not open, it throws error and subsequent scripts are not executed. The execution just stops there. I am getting this error : `nc: connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9005 (tcp) failed: Connection refused`

Comment: The `&&` says to only do the `sudo kill` if `nc` is successful.  If you have `set -e` any error will cause the script to abort, but by itself, this simply runs `sudo kill` only if `nc` succeeded.